# Asymptotics of $\Sigma x^n/n^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am  looking for asymptotics of

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{x^n}{n^p}$$

in terms of $N$, where $x>1$ and  $p$ is a  positive number.

So I am looking for a $O(f(N))$ type result.  For example what is the approximate value of 
$\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{5^n}{n^2}$ for large $N$. One possibility is probably something like $\frac{5^N}{N^2} (a+\frac{b}{N}+\frac{c}{N^2}+\cdots)$.

Comment: The asymptotics is very simple. The series does not converge for such $x$.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are seeking?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, you may want to be specific about what you are asking OP to do too :D

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  as N increases what function would be a good approximation

Answer (score 4):

By Taylor expansion, we see that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{x^n}{n^p}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k!}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(n\ln x)^k}{n^p}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^k}{k!}\sum_{n=1}^Nn^{k-p}$$

We then have by the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula):

$$\sum_{n=1}^Nn^{k-p}=\frac{N^{k-p+1}}{k-p+1}+\frac{N^{k-p}}2+\zeta(k-p)+\frac{(k-p)N^{k-p-1}}{12}+\mathcal O(N^{k-p-3})$$

where $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).  Thus, we end up with

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^k}{k!}\left(\frac{N^{k-p+1}}{k-p+1}+\frac{N^{k-p}}2+\zeta(k-p)+\frac{(k-p)N^{k-p-1}}{12}+\mathcal O(N^{k-p-3})\right)$$

---

By the [Abel summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula) with $\phi(n)=\frac1{n^p}$ and $a_n=x^n$, we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{x^n}{n^p}=\frac{1-x^{N+1}}{(1-x)N^p}+p\int_1^N\frac{1-x^{\lfloor t\rfloor+1}}{(1-x)t^{p+1}}\ dt\\=\frac1{1-x}\left(\frac{2-x^{N+1}}{N^p}-1-\int_1^N\frac{x^{\lfloor t\rfloor+1}}{t^{p+1}}\ dt\right)$$

And the last integral may be approximated.

Answer (score 4):

We find 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{x^n}{n^p} 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^p} 
 - \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^p} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^p} - x^{N+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k+N+1)^p}  
 \qquad (\textrm{let } n=N+1+k) \\
&= \mathrm{Li}_p(x) - x^{N+1}\Phi(x,p,N+1)  
 \qquad \textrm{(polylogarithm and Lerch transcendent)} \\
&\sim \frac{x^{N+1}}{x-1} \frac{1}{(N+1)^p}. 
\end{align*}
In the last step we use the known asymptotics for the Lerch transcendent. Higher order corrections can be found. 
See, for example, 
Chelo Ferreira, José L. López, *Asymptotic expansions of the Hurwitz–Lerch zeta function*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, Volume 298, Issue 1, 2004, Pages 210-224, ISSN 0022-247X, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2004.05.040.

**Addendum**

As @martycohen notes, the expansion in the paper is for $x\in\mathbb{C}-[1,\infty)$. 
It should be possible to make a complex analytic argument that the asymptotic expansion above is valid for $x>1$. 
Rather than do that, instead I will present a more elementary approach.

Let $1<k<N$. Then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{x^n}{n^p}
= \sum_{n=N-k}^N\frac{x^n}{n^p}
+  \sum_{n=1}^{N-k-1}\frac{x^n}{n^p}.$$
But 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-k-1}\frac{x^n}{n^p} 
< \sum_{n=1}^{N-k-1}x^n 
= \frac{x^{N-k}-x}{x-1}$$
and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-k-1}\frac{x^n}{n^p} 
> \frac{1}{N^p}\sum_{n=1}^{N-k-1}x^n 
= \frac{1}{N^p}\frac{x^{N-k}-x}{x-1}$$
and so 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-k-1}\frac{x^n}{n^p} = O(x^{N-k}).$$
Therefore, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{x^n}{n^p} 
= \sum_{n=N-k+1}^N\frac{x^n}{n^p} + O(x^{N-k}).$$

Comment: Hm, your last approximation is very similar to the second half of my last approximation.  :-)

Comment: OP wanted x > 1.

Comment: @martycohen: I appreciate your close reading. I have added something above to address this.

Answer (score 2):

Just playing around to see what happens.

If $x > 1$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{x^n}{n^p}
&=x^N\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{x^{n-N}}{n^p}\\
&=x^N\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \dfrac{x^{-n}}{(N-n)^p}\\
&=\dfrac{x^N}{N^p}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \dfrac{x^{-n}}{(1-n/N)^p}\\
&=\dfrac{x^N}{N^p}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x^{-n}(1-n/N)^{-p}\\
&=\dfrac{x^N}{N^p}\left(1+\dfrac1{x(1-1/N)^p}+\dfrac1{x^2(1-2/N)^p}+...\right)\\
\end{array}
$

To see how (or if)
this converges,
look at the ratio of
consecutive terms.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x^{-n-1}(1-(n+1)/N)^{-p}}{x^{-n}(1-n/N)^{-p}}
&=\dfrac{(N-n)^p}{x(N-n-1)^{p}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{x(1-1/(N-n))^{p}}\\
&\approx\dfrac{1}{x(1-p/(N-n))}
\qquad\text{for small } n\\
&\approx\dfrac{1}{x}(1+p/(N-n))\\
&\approx\dfrac{1}{x}(1+p/(N(1-n/N))\\
&\approx\dfrac{1}{x}(1+(p/N)(1+n/N))\\
&=\dfrac{1}{x}(1+p/N+pn/N^2)\\
&\approx\dfrac{1}{x}(1+p/N)\\
\end{array}
$

This is $1$ when
$x(1-1/(N-n))^{p}
=1$
or
$1-1/(N-n)
=x^{-1/p}
$
or
$N-n
=\dfrac{1}{1-x^{-1/p}}
$.

Using the approximate ratio of
$\approx\dfrac{1+p/N}{x}
$,
the approximate expansion is
$\dfrac{x^N}{N^p}\left(1+\dfrac{1+p/N}{x}+\dfrac{(1+p/N)^2}{x^2}+...\right)
$.

That's as far as I can take it now.

Hope this helps.